# Make word plural if number is greater than one

Tags: c#

I have a console application in which if a user gets a certain number of questions right, the console will then display "You have answered 'x' question/s correctly".
My point being, I want to display "question" if the number of correct answers is one, and similarly "questions" if the number is above one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try reading up on if and else statements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement or a quick [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to format the string with the number and "s".

```
int amount = 1; //Change to see difference
string text = string.Format("You have answered {0} question{1} correctly.", amount, amount > 1 || amount == 0 ? "s" : string.Empty);
```

If the amount of questions are more than 1 or equal to 0, just add an s

Another, more readable solution is less compact, but works:

```
int amount = 1;
if (amount == 1)
    text = "You have answered 1 question correctly";
else
    text = string.Format("You have answered {0} questions correctly", amount);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and not just thumbing it down (I'm new to programming and as obvious as my question may seem to others... Well let's just say it wasn't obvious to me. So thanks again.

Comment: @Cyral is there a .net version of ruby's pluralize method (which can handle complex words like 'fish', plural for crow is not crows but a 'murder' of crows etc.)?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.pluralizationservices.pluralizationservice.aspx :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numberOfCorrectAnswers == 1)
    printLine("You have answered 1 question correctly.");
else
    printLine(string.Format("You have answered {0} questions correctly", numberOfCorrectAnswers));
```

where "printLine" is some print method.

Answer (score -1):

if int(quantity) > 1:
print("That will be a total of" + str(total))
print("Sounds good. " + name, "Your " + quantity +" " + order + "s will be ready in a minute!")
else:
print("That will be a total of"+ str(total))
print("Sounds good " + name, ". Your " + quantity +" " + order, "will be ready in a minute!")

#This only if you want to make the ai code say something